# LayerDrawable remove a layer

Tags: android, android-drawable, layerdrawable

How can a layer be removed from `LayerDrawable`? `addLayer` can be used to add a layer, but I don't see a function that can be used to remove a layer.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html

Answer (score 3):

After looking at documentation there is no direct method to remove a layer.
however method `public void setDrawable (int index, Drawable drawable)` can be used to change drawable of a layer so may be replacing a layer with an empty (transparent or null) drawable will give you desired result.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the layer transparent by setting the alpha value to zero:

```
  //ld is of LayerDrawable type
Drawable layer = ((LayerDrawable)(ld)).getDrawable(index);
layer.mutate().setAlpha(0);
```